# Blender 2.79 to 3.0, Removed toolbar?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, interface, object-mode

I'm a bit late to switching to Blender 3, but I had my reasons.  Mainly to wait for improvements since a lot of necessary UI features were removed in the update, partially waiting for a critical addon to be updated, mostly just because I didn't have the time to waste on learning while working on my current job at the time.

I am trying to learn to adapt my workflow but it seems like a significant number of options are moved to different menus or not accessible via UI anymore at all.

Like tool bar on the left side of the main viewport, the one with the "Tools" "Create" "Physics" etc tabs.  Mainly what I use the most is the "Add Primitive" menu.

Where is it?  Why is it gone?  How do I get it back?  How can I access it without using keyboard shortcuts?  Second question, how do I get the custom properties to display their value instead of just a "edit value" button that opens a window that doesn't even have enough room to show the full value?

I understand the praise the new Blender gets but what I don't understand is why criticisms or questions like this are met with ridicule and snark.  There was no reason to remove this, and there is certainly no reason why users shouldn't be able to add it back without having to learn python and implement it themselves.

I would very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the functions you mention (such as add primitive) can be found from the menu(s) at the top. There are also further "point and click" (sometimes hold) mesh manipulation tools in the left-hand toolbar (both highlighted with red). Other mesh tools such as *Object Data Properties*, *Physics*, *Constraints*, *etc...* can be found on the right side properties tabs (highlighted yellow):

[image: Tools]

Also, I'm not entirely certain what the problem is you are having with edit custom property. The property window is usually accessed as shown below. Is the problem that you have a large value and the window can't be resized?

[image: Custom]

Comment: The "Add" section is entirely missing for both object and edit mode.  I am guessing this is an issue on my end as I can't find any reason why that may be the case via search so I'll look into a fresh install.

As for the custom properties, the ones I use primarily are of the type "python" and the value isn't visible at all unless you edit it and the text bar won't display everything at once. I need to be able to look at what the value is at a glance so I can change something else in another part of the UI simultaneously.  It might seem small but it drastically slows my workflow over time.